# Whitelabel Error Page while run simple service

Tags: java, spring

I have created Spring Starter Project in STS (Spring Tool Suite) with simple Controller:

```
@RestController
public class GreetingController {

    private static final String template = "Hello, %s!";
    private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

    @GetMapping("/greeting")
    public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(value = "name", defaultValue = "World") String name) {
        return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(), String.format(template, name));
    }
}
```

as shown in [tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/).

I run service from IDE and it starts fine. But when I go to http://localhost:8080/greeting?name=User I get error:

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Thu Oct 01 10:25:10 PDT 2020
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
```

Why I'm getting this error? How to fix that?

UPD

After adding more log I got mapping to error:

```
2020-10-02 06:17:46.078[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m4851[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36ms.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping[0;39m [2m:[0;39m 2 mappings in 'requestMappingHandlerMapping'
[2m2020-10-02 06:17:46.136[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m4851[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
[2m2020-10-02 06:17:46.142[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m4851[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mcom.example.demo.Demo1Application       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Started Demo1Application in 1.221 seconds (JVM running for 1.934)
[2m2020-10-02 06:17:51.491[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m4851[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-1][0;39m [36mo.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
[2m2020-10-02 06:17:51.493[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m4851[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-1][0;39m [36mo.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
[2m2020-10-02 06:17:51.496[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m4851[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-1][0;39m [36mo.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Completed initialization in 3 ms
[2m2020-10-02 06:17:51.508[0;39m [32mTRACE[0;39m [35m4851[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-1][0;39m [36ms.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping[0;39m [2m:[0;39m 2 matching mappings: [{ /error, produces [text/html]}, { /error}]
[2m2020-10-02 06:17:51.509[0;39m [32mTRACE[0;39m [35m4851[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-1][0;39m [36ms.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you get `404` then obviously your controller is not registered. It is difficult to help you if we are missing other source code.

Maybe your controller is in foreign package. Spring boot use component scan by default for all packages (and subpackages) of your main Spring boot class (class with `@SpringBootApplication` annotation).

To find issue, just add

```
logging.level.org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping=TRACE
```

to your `application.properties` and search for `greeting` string in logs
you should find something like

```
2020-10-01 19:49:12.610 TRACE 36840 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : 
    c.t.t.c.RootController:
    {GET /}: welcome()
    {GET /greeting}: greeting(Model)
```

Comment: got mapping to error in log file.  More details in question body UPD